# create thicker border to the end of the row in rowspan using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a dynamic table and have the rowspan then to create thick border end of the row when rowspan is available in table. Please help me the issues javascript/Jquery...

Comment: Where is your code? Show us what you have so far :)

Comment: Use css `tr:last-child` to do that. Share your code may I help you.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the fiddle

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/35xx34w1/1/)

All you need to do is check with jquery that if the element td has attribute 'rowspan' or not, if yes then style that element

```
 $.each($('td'), function(){
        if($(this).attr('rowspan'))
            $(this).css("border","5px solid #111");
    });
```